# Виртуальное окружение PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня вопрос.

Вроде в Pycharme автоматически активируется виртуальное окружение.

Почему у меня в терминале вместо  отображается PS. И что вообще это значит?

Заранее спасибо за ответ

[image]

Comment: Сокращение от **P**ower**S**hell. Чтобы вы не забыли где находитесь.

Comment: Я не понимаю, а как убрать это? Или это и есть venv?

Comment: @Timofey зачем это убирать? Если будете под linux - там как раз будет venv

Comment: `Вроде в Pycharme автоматически активируется виртуальное окружение.` - активируется только если при создании проекта вы создали его или вручную потом указали интерпретатор из окружения как интерпретатор проекта. Сейчас не похоже, что у вас что-то активируется вообще.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, т.к. вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS - [powershell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) , если у вас оно написано - значит никакого виртуального окружения нет. Это всего лишь оболочка, в которой вы находитесь([см тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949892/using-powershell-as-terminal-in-intellij-idea-ides-like-pycharm-phpstorm-or-rub)) Если нужна обычная командная строка, надо вписать cmd.exe.

Теперь по поводу виртуального окружения. Даже если вы сидите под pworshell, то при виртуальном окружении будет написано следующее:

```
(venv) PS D:\System\Documents\Si.....\>
```

Поэтому виртуальное окружение у вас либо не создано, либо не активировано как сделать первое и второе посмотрите в интернете.(Причем как с использованием pyCharm, так и без него)

Answer (score 0):

Так и должно быть. PyCharm после создания проекта с любой средой в качества пути для консоли (в данном случаем PowerShell) использует путь до самой папки с проектом.

```
PS C:\Users\zero\PycharmProjects\zeroNotepads> dir


Directory: C:\Users\zero\PycharmProjects\zeroNotepads


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        20.02.2022      8:50                .idea # папка для конфигурации проекта PyCharm
d-----        01.02.2022     18:36                scripts
d-----        01.02.2022     14:49                venv # это и есть папка виртуальной среды
-a----        01.02.2022     18:35             70 zeronotepads.py


PS C:\Users\zero\PycharmProjects\zeroNotepads>
```

Здесь показан пример с моим проектом в котором присутствует virtualenv. Сам терминал открыт в PyCharm.

Буквы **PS** обозначают то, что это терминал PowerShell, встроенный в ОС Windows по умолчанию при установке системы.

**UPD:** Для заметки, у меня используется **PyCharm Professional 2021.3**.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в PyCharm:

```
File > Settings > Tools > Terminal
```

Внутри Terminal:

```
Application Settings > Shell path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```

Сохраните изменения и перейдите в терминал. Теперь у вас должно отображаться без знака `PS`

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).